# Sort List of String In A Variable

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

I have the below code, list of string that I'd like to sort.

```
LIST="APP_PATH_10_TARGET APP_PATH_1_TARGET APP_PATH_2_TARGET APP_PATH_3_TARGET"
```

My goal is to sort it into:

```
"APP_PATH_1_TARGET APP_PATH_2_TARGET APP_PATH_3_TARGET APP_PATH_10_TARGET"
```

So I did this:

```
SORTEDLIST=$(echo ${LIST} | sort -t"_" -k3n,3)
```

But its still showing:

```
SORTEDLIST=APP_PATH_10_TARGET APP_PATH_1_TARGET APP_PATH_2_TARGET APP_PATH_3_TARGET
```

I can't find out why the sort doesn't work.

================================================================

Update:
This is the code that I'm working on.

I have this ENV variables:

```
APP_PATH_1_TARGET="/prd/example/1"
APP_PATH_2_TARGET="/prd/example/2"
APP_PATH_3_TARGET="/prd/example/3"
APP_PATH_10_TARGET="/prd/example/4"
```

The code that doesn't work, because the list is not in expected sequence:

```
create_app_dir(){
  # Get all variables with name starts with APP_PATH*
  local PARAMLIST=`echo ${!APP_PATH*}`
  echo "PARAMLIST=${PARAMLIST}"
  local SORTEDLIST=$(sort -t_ -k3n <<< ${PARAMLIST// /$'\n'}|tr -s "\n" " ")
  echo "SORTEDLIST=${SORTEDLIST}"

  # Iterate the list and create dir if doesn't exist
  for p in ${SORTEDLIST}; do
    if [[ "${p}" = *_TARGET ]] && [ ! -d "${p}" ]; then

      echo "[+] Creating application directory:${!p}"
      ./make_dir.sh "${!p}"

      if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "[-] Error: Unable to create dir." >&2
        return 1
      fi
    fi
  done
}
```

Comment: What is the actual sequence you are getting in the sortedList?

Comment: @Abhinandanprasad Exactly this LIST="APP_PATH_10_TARGET APP_PATH_1_TARGET APP_PATH_2_TARGET APP_PATH_3_TARGET"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because sort is only working with lines by definition. man sort:

> sort - sort lines of text files

```
SORTEDLIST=$(sort -t"_" -k3n,3 <<< ${LIST// /$'\n'}|tr -s "\n" " ")
```

Comment: I've just tried that and still it doesnt work. I've updated the question with portion of code that I'm working on, with your proposed solution.

Comment: @FadhlieIkram Both mine and his solution (they're almost the same) work on my machine with your example code.

Comment: That's weird, its not on my machine. Maybe different bash version. Anyways I've managed to make it work, but only after I iterate the list into a temporary file, which I then call for sorting. I'm accepting this answer and thanks for your help :).

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 SORTEDLIST = $(sort -t_ -k3n filename | tr -s '\n\r' ' ')
```

or

```
  SORTEDLIST = $(sort -t_ -k3n filename | tr -s '\n' ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

`sort` arranges *lines* in order.  To sort *words*, you want to re-write each word as a line:

```
SORTEDLIST=$(printf "%s\n" $LIST | sort -t_ -k3n)
```

Since you're using Bash, you'd be better using a real list, so that you can get the quoting right:

```
LIST=(APP_PATH_10_TARGET APP_PATH_1_TARGET APP_PATH_2_TARGET APP_PATH_3_TARGET)
SORTEDLIST=($(printf "%s\n" "${LIST[@]}" | sort -t_ -k3n))

for p in "${SORTEDLIST[@]}"
```

Also, you should avoid using all-uppercase for your shell variables; this convention is used to indicate environment variables intended to change program behaviour.